# Sort Files in Google Drive Public View

Tags: google-drive-api

With the web interface to Google Drive, I know how to sort files in a directory. But when I share a folder by sending someone the "Link to share" (because they don't have a Google Drive account) they can view the files in the public shared directory but the files are always sorted alphabetically. There doesn't appear to be a menu in this limited interface to specify how to sort. How can the user sort, or how can I specify the default sort for a folder? (I would like to sort by file modification time.) I am using the Google Drive API and am fine with a solution that requires its use.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no way to do this at the moment. I've raised a feature request which you are welcome to vote on. The link is at https://www.google.com/moderator/#15/e=c81a2&t=c81a2.4c&f=c81a2.6af5c7&q=c81a2.6af5c7

Comment: I would like to vote on this feature request too, as it would appear after 8 years it still has not been implemented. Do you have a working link for it now (am not surprised link doesn't work after 8 years!).